# Probability That an $n$ Digit Integer's Digits Will Have a Product of Zero

Tags: probability, combinatorics, limits, proof-verification

**The Question**

Let $d(n):\mathbb{N} \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ be a function which given an input $n$ will map it to the product of its digits. Show that for sufficiently large $n$ the probability that $d(n) = 0$ is $1$.

**My Work**

There are $9 \times 10^{n-1}$ possible $n$ digit integers. There are $9^n$ possible $n$ digit numbers with no zeros. Therefore, there are $9 \times 10^{n-1} - 9^n$ possible $n$ digit integers with at least one zero. The probability of an $n$ digit natural number $k$ fulfilling the property $d(k) = 0$ is $\frac{(9 \times 10^{n-1} - 9^n)}{9\times 10^{n-1}}$

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(9 \times 10^{n-1} - 9^n)}{9\times 10^{n-1}} = 1$ (Via Wolfram Alpha)

**My Question**

This is a question I wondered about while working on a programming problem involving digit products. I don't know if the steps I took are correct or if what I'm trying to prove is even correct, so some verification would be nice. I'm also wondering if there is another solution to this problem, if it is correct?

Comment: Your count of the number of integers expressible with at most  $n$ digits is wrong. There are $10^n$ of them ($0 \ldots 10^n -1)$. Of these $9^n$ contain no zeroes and (it can be shown that) $9^n/10^n$ tends to $0$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$.

Comment: @RobArthan: They are presumably using the standard convention that the first digit of an "$n$-digit number" must be nonzero.

Comment: @Eric: The question is surely asking us to show that the probability of a number drawn at random in the range $0 \ldots n$ having $d(n) = 0$ tends to $1$ as $n$ tends to $\infty$. That means we have to look at $k$-digit numbers for $0< k < \log_{10}n$.

Comment: @RobArthan: I doubt that OP knows for sure what they actually are trying to prove.  Your version is certainly a reasonable way to make the statement precise, but that doesn't mean that what they said is "wrong", since the problem isn't even clearly defined to begin with.

Comment: @EricWofsey: maybe, but I can't see how the **question** can possibly be interpreted as restricted to numbers $n$ in the range $10^{k-1} \ldots 10^k$ for some $k$. Over to the OP to give a clear statement of the question.

Comment: @RobArthan "Your count of the number of integers expressible with at most nn digits is wrong. There are 10n10n of them (0…10n−1)" sorry if I wasn't clear, but I define my natural numbers as not being able to start with 0. (e.g. 0100 isn't a valid construct)

Comment: Yes, well you need to fix the statement of your question to address that. There are $10^k$ natural numbers less than $n = 10^k$. Nothing you've said under "**The question**" in your question suggests that we are to ignore $10$% of those numbers (the ones less than $10^{k-1}$)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is basically correct, but the statement you are trying to prove does not make sense.  What does it mean to say "for sufficiently large $n$ the probability that $d(n) = 0$ is $1$"?  For any particular value of $n$, $d(n)$ has a definite, specific value, and so either $d(n)=0$ or $d(n)\neq 0$ (it's not a matter of probability).  To talk about probabilities in a meaningful way, you need to say how you are choosing $n$ at random (say, you are choosing it randomly from a certain range of possible values, with all values being equally likely).  Moreover, the phrase "for sufficiently large $n$..." means "there exists a constant $C$ such that for *all* $n>C$...".  In this case, that would mean you are asserting that $d(n)=0$ for *all* $n>C$, which is not true (since you could take $n$ to be a number with more digits than $C$, none of which are $0$).

What you have proven (correctly) is that if you let $p_N$ be the probability that $d(n)=0$ if $n$ is a randomly chosen $N$-digit positive integer, then $\lim_{N\to\infty}p_N=1$.  That is, if you randomly choose $n$ among all $N$-digit numbers for some fixed $N$, the probability that $d(n)=0$ *approaches* $1$ as you make $N$ larger and larger.

Comment: " but the statement you are trying to prove does not make sense. What does it mean to say "for sufficiently large nn the probability that d(n)=0d(n)=0 is 11"?". What I was trying to prove is that if you randomly select an $n$ digit natural number from all possible $n$ digit natural numbers, the probability that the natural number as a digit product of 0 approaches 1 as n grows larger and larger.

Comment: He's pointing out that your question "Show that for sufficiently large $n$ the probability that $d(n)=0$ is $1$." is poorly worded. It should have specifically mentioned choosing a random $n$ digit number, as your comment does. It's a tiny detail, but otherwise considering the probability of $d(n)$ doesn't make sense, without a specific number. For example, if we take the number $123$, then the probability of the product of its digits being $0$ is definitely $0$. If we take $300$, the probability of its product of digits being $0$ is $1$.

Comment: Besides needing to say how you're choosing $n$, there is also an important distinction between "for sufficiently large $n$ the probability is $1$" and "the probability approaches $1$".  In the first case you are saying the probability actually _is_ exactly $1$ for any large enough value of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

You solved this correctly. Another way to see this is any digit (except the leading digit) has a $\frac{9}{10}$ chance of not being  $0$. Then the probability that a random $n$ digit number's digits' product will not be zero is $(\frac{9}{10})^{n-1}$. We see as $n \to \infty$, this product goes to $0$.